# Trying to move all files from one S3 bucket to another using node.js and exec + aws cli

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm not a strong coder, but trying to create a Lambda function using **node.js** which runs via Lambda cron once a day to move files in an S3 bucket to an "archive" bucket.

Tried various methods

```
sudo nodejs -e "console.log(require('./index').handler({}));"
```

My output from local machine is:

```
Running MyApp
Source mybucket
Target mybucket-archive
Account test
undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
var aws = require('./node_modules/aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();

console.log('Running myapp');
console.log(JSON.stringify(context.invokedFunctionArn).split(':')[4]);
var AccountNumber = (JSON.stringify(context.invokedFunctionArn).split(':')[4]);
if(AccountNumber == '123456789000') { SourceBucket = 'mybucket-test'; }     //test account
if(AccountNumber == '198765432101') { SourceBucket = 'mybucket-prod'; }  //prod account

var targetBucket = SourceBucket+"-archive"       

//Debug?
console.log("Source", SourceBucket);
console.log("Target", targetBucket);
console.log("Account", AccountNumber);

exports.handler = function () {  
//  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec("aws s3 mv s3://", +SourceBucket+ "/incoming/test/ s3://" +targetBucket+ "/incoming/test/ --recursive"), (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    //exec(echo 'hello world'), (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        // node couldn't execute the command
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }

      // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      }
    };
```

What I'm expecting is that aws cli is invoked and moves files from primary bucket to archive bucket.

We only expect 10-20 small 1kb txt files to be uploaded per day so we expect this should run within the Lambda requirements. This has to run via Lambda cron as s3 events are used on other lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For moving files from one s3 bucket to another we can use the `aws-sdk` which is an SDK of Javascript. 
References:
https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');


const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  // Input the region that you are using here.
  region: 'eu-west-1',
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) {
  const sourceBucket = 'bucket-1';
  const destinationBucket = 'bucket-2';
  const files = await s3
    .listObjects({
      Bucket: sourceBucket,
    })
    .promise();

  return Promise.all(
    files.Contents.map(async content => {
      await s3
        .copyObject({
          Bucket: destinationBucket,
          CopySource: `/${sourceBucket}/${content.Key}`,
          Key: content.Key,
        })
        .promise();

      return s3
        .deleteObject({
          Bucket: sourceBucket,
          Key: content.Key,
        })
        .promise();
    })
  );
}
```

You can also do it using aws cli and child process.
The bug in your code is that you have a "," before the SourceBucket when you are trying to append the command. :-) So the command was never executed.

```js
async function handler(event, context) {
  const SourceBucket = 'bucket-1';
  const targetBucket = 'bucket-2';
  const exec = require('child_process').exec;
  console.log(
    'aws s3 mv s3://'
    +SourceBucket +
      '/ s3://' +
      targetBucket +
      '/ --recursive'
  );
  exec(
    'aws s3 mv s3://'
    +SourceBucket +
      '/ s3://' +
      targetBucket +
      '/ --recursive'
  ),
    (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      //exec(echo 'hello world'), (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        // node couldn't execute the command
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }

      // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    };
}
```